# How to insert output from Cox regression on the graph

Tags: r

I have got survival data, based on quartiles of `delta_mon1_baselone_to_3d`. Outcomes is `mace`.

Cox regression for each quartile are obtained with this code:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytidbits)
library(survivalAnalysis)
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggpubr)

df$quantile <- df$delta_mon1_baseline_to_d3
df$stratum <- findInterval(df$quantile, quantile(df$quantile, na.rm = TRUE)[-5])
df$stratum <- factor(df$stratum)
cox <- coxph(Surv(mace_months_date_vs_date_sample, mace) ~ stratum, data = df)
```

The output gives me that:

```
               coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
stratum2 -4.780e-01  6.201e-01  9.135e-01 -0.523    0.601
stratum3 -1.211e+00  2.980e-01  1.155e+00 -1.048    0.295
stratum4 -2.015e+01  1.767e-09  1.277e+04 -0.002    0.999

         exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
stratum2 6.201e-01  1.613e+00   0.10348     3.715
stratum3 2.980e-01  3.356e+00   0.03097     2.867
stratum4 1.767e-09  5.661e+08   0.00000       Inf

Concordance= 0.731  (se = 0.08 )
Likelihood ratio test= 4.99  on 3 df,   p=0.2
Wald test            = 1.14  on 3 df,   p=0.8
Score (logrank) test = 3.86  on 3 df,   p=0.3
```

I would like to put these outcomes on the graph as the attached figure.

[image]

Here is the code I have used to get this graph:

```
custom_theme <- function(){
  theme_survminer() %+replace%
    theme(
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"),
      plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.9)
    )
}

df$surv <- Surv(df$mace_months_date_vs_date_sample, df$mace)
mod <- coxph(surv ~ strata(stratum), 
             data = df)

ggsurv_uni1 <- ggsurvplot(survfit(mod, data = df),
           pval = FALSE,
           ggtheme = custom_theme(), 
           censor = FALSE,
           legend = c(0.5, 0.2),
           legend.title = element_blank(),
           legend.labs = c(
             "Quartile 1.",
             "Quartile 2. HR 0.62 (95% CI 0.1-3.72), P=0.60",
             "Quartile 3. HR 0.30 (95% CI 0.03-2.87), P=0.30",
             "Quartile 4."),
            xlab = "Follow-up (months)",
           font.x = c(size = 15),
           ylab = "Survival from MACE",
           font.y = c(size = 15),
           ylim = c(0, 1.05),
           break.y.by = 0.2,
           axes.offset = FALSE,
           palette = c("blue", "dark red", "green", "orange"))

ggsurv_uni1$plot <- ggsurv_uni1$plot + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 8, color = "black"))

ggsurv_uni1
```

At the moment I can only annotate (adding text manually) but I would like to put it from the cox regression analysis directly the hazard ratio and the 95%CI with 2 decimals, and the P-values with 2 decimals when it P>0.009 otherwise, with 3 decimals.

Here are my data:

```
      ID age     sex  mace mace_months_date_vs_date_sample trop egfr  dm smoke  delta_mon1_baseline_to_d3
 1    44 52        1     1                              30 2600  56    1     0                       -822.  
 2    32 66        1     0                              73 1710  90    1     0                       -562.  
 3    20 56        1     1                               5 NA    75    0     1                       -502.  
 4    17 44        1     0                              77 840   71    0     0                       -389.  
 5    52 49        1     0                              74 1740  71    0     1                       -372.  
 6    57 58        1     0                              74 5010  68    0     1                       -308.  
 7    79 68        1     0                              45 776   90    0     0                       -284.  
 8    14 74        1     1                               6 7120  78    0     0                       -279.  
 9   223 63        1     0                              46 4281  90    0     0                       -218.  
10    56 43        1     0                              70 1360  90    1     0                       -173.  
11    50 54        1     0                              70 15300 90    0     1                       -163.  
12    31 47        0     0                              72 6490  77    1     1                        -95.7 
13    35 47        1     0                              77 NA    83    0     0                        -71.0 
14    36 64        1     1                               5 15940 52    0     1                        -69.7 
15    15 65        1     1                              43 6300  49    1     0                        -69.6 
16    12 57        1     0                              71 6020  88    0     1                        -66.5 
17    43 59        0     0                              74 2100  84    0     1                        -58.8 
18    22 46        1     0                              77 5330  88    0     1                        -29.3 
19    54 59        1     0                              71 1500  81    1     1                        -25.7 
20    26 66        1     0                              77 500   51    0     0                        -12.5 
21    29 73        0     0                              77 NA    51    0     0                         -2.99
22    25 54        1     0                              73 1080  87    0     0                          2.81
23    39 54        1     0                              74 990   77    0     0                         32.9 
24    47 62        1     0                              69 1420  85    0     0                         33.0 
25    49 54        1     1                              28 NA    76    1     0                         44.1 
26    24 47        1     0                              77 2390  90    0     1                         47.7 
27    45 51        0     0                              73 3710  65    0     1                         55.9 
28    30 73        0     0                              68 3340  48    1     1                        117.  
29    16 57        1     0                              73 180   99    0     1                        131.  
30    55 47        1     0                              70 NA    90    0     1                        131.  
31    37 81        1     0                              74 NA    99    1     1                        147.  
32    21 46        1     0                              75 3600  87    0     1                        153.  
33    60 72        1     0                              76 470   62    0     0                        160.  
34    18 56        1     0                              69 6390  90    0     1                        165.  
35    13 53        1     0                              69 1970  87    1     1                        180.  
36    19 66        1     0                              78 9320  59    0     0                        180.  
37    33 59        1     0                              69 2260  79    0     1                        193.  
38   139 39        0     0                              58 NA    90    0     1                        209.  
39    38 55        1     0                              78 3930  90    1     0                        244.  
40    27 28        1     0                              71 6440  90    0     1                        248.  
41    58 36        1     0                              76 NA    78    1     1                        327.  
42    61 48        1     0                              76 4470  90    0     1                        336.  
43    42 38        1     0                              69 1800  69    0     1                        375.  
44    28 76        1     0                              71 40    90    1     1                        419.
```

Here is the console output:

```
structure(list(ID = c(44L, 32L, 20L, 17L, 52L, 57L, 79L, 14L, 
223L, 56L, 50L, 31L, 35L, 36L, 15L, 12L, 43L, 22L, 54L, 26L, 
29L, 25L, 39L, 47L, 49L, 24L, 45L, 30L, 16L, 55L, 37L, 21L, 60L, 
18L, 13L, 19L, 33L, 139L, 38L, 27L, 58L, 61L, 42L, 28L, 121L, 
192L, 120L, 68L, 41L, 23L, 216L, 136L, 88L, 87L, 182L, 93L, 154L, 
94L, 116L, 145L, 228L, 76L, 63L, 59L, 219L, 175L, 164L, 181L, 
234L, 146L, 242L, 71L, 67L, 187L, 128L, 151L, 215L, 132L, 173L, 
124L, 119L, 224L, 140L, 221L, 172L, 115L, 103L, 73L, 194L, 106L, 
193L, 148L, 156L, 203L, 100L, 81L, 190L, 206L, 233L, 189L, 105L, 
220L, 85L, 11L, 205L, 131L, 1L, 225L, 183L, 213L, 7L, 147L, 134L, 
86L, 69L, 212L, 199L, 75L, 137L, 191L, 245L, 111L, 153L, 112L, 
89L, 243L, 109L, 165L, 95L, 231L, 5L, 168L, 159L, 6L, 179L, 77L, 
155L, 171L, 174L, 84L, 102L, 207L, 230L, 138L, 188L, 241L, 72L, 
235L, 211L, 127L, 237L, 70L, 210L, 110L, 133L, 2L, 218L, 180L, 
229L, 65L, 130L, 96L, 226L, 152L, 197L, 178L, 141L, 195L, 92L, 
162L, 201L, 217L, 222L, 208L, 104L, 160L, 66L, 74L, 185L, 177L, 
123L, 184L, 204L, 227L, 125L, 83L, 8L, 143L, 9L, 3L, 117L, 10L, 
198L, 244L, 108L, 34L, 214L, 4L, 97L, 200L, 113L, 80L, 166L, 
98L, 238L, 239L, 114L, 167L, 64L, 157L, 90L, 149L, 129L, 170L, 
91L, 135L, 122L, 240L, 99L, 236L, 144L, 53L, 176L, 107L, 232L, 
163L, 142L, 118L, 126L, 158L, 186L, 82L, 78L, 48L, 62L, 209L, 
196L, 46L, 150L, 161L, 169L, 101L, 202L, 51L, 40L), age = c(52L, 
66L, 56L, 44L, 49L, 58L, 68L, 74L, 63L, 43L, 54L, 47L, 47L, 64L, 
65L, 57L, 59L, 46L, 59L, 66L, 73L, 54L, 54L, 62L, 54L, 47L, 51L, 
73L, 57L, 47L, 81L, 46L, 72L, 56L, 53L, 66L, 59L, 39L, 55L, 28L, 
36L, 48L, 38L, 76L, NA, 59L, 71L, 58L, 57L, 54L, 69L, 49L, 65L, 
48L, 35L, 44L, 65L, 56L, 66L, 41L, 55L, 52L, 67L, 61L, 65L, 61L, 
75L, 56L, 37L, 75L, 68L, 59L, 52L, 59L, 59L, 63L, 62L, 57L, 48L, 
65L, 41L, 60L, 77L, 66L, 50L, 51L, 81L, 61L, 64L, 48L, 63L, 78L, 
79L, 51L, 74L, 52L, 73L, 82L, 58L, 72L, 63L, 67L, 72L, 51L, 68L, 
41L, 66L, 69L, 60L, 66L, 71L, 45L, 81L, 52L, 67L, 58L, 63L, 47L, 
63L, 67L, 62L, 72L, 75L, 46L, 73L, 57L, 75L, 68L, 68L, 73L, 51L, 
59L, 59L, 60L, 54L, 62L, 64L, 48L, 73L, 79L, 58L, 46L, 75L, 63L, 
68L, 60L, 54L, 78L, 54L, 46L, 49L, 67L, 79L, 54L, 47L, 51L, 66L, 
61L, 64L, 79L, 73L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 76L, 75L, 56L, 76L, 54L, 82L, 
62L, 57L, 53L, 42L, 63L, 37L, 66L, 46L, 76L, 39L, 51L, 80L, 69L, 
76L, 48L, 65L, 59L, 76L, 57L, 66L, 69L, 68L, 72L, 62L, 56L, 51L, 
60L, 71L, 68L, 77L, 28L, 62L, 51L, 61L, 56L, 72L, 79L, 62L, 68L, 
68L, 49L, 75L, 64L, 48L, 51L, 68L, 68L, 70L, 73L, 54L, 47L, 79L, 
40L, 52L, 58L, 69L, 61L, 44L, 57L, 55L, 43L, 61L, 44L, 77L, 35L, 
74L, 72L, 60L, 44L, 53L, 61L, NA, 80L, 73L, 72L), sex = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), mace = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mace_months_date_vs_date_sample = c(30L, 
73L, 5L, 77L, 74L, 74L, 45L, 6L, 46L, 70L, 70L, 72L, 77L, 5L, 
43L, 71L, 74L, 77L, 71L, 77L, 77L, 73L, 74L, 69L, 28L, 77L, 73L, 
68L, 73L, 70L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 69L, 69L, 78L, 69L, 58L, 78L, 71L, 
76L, 76L, 69L, 71L, 43L, 44L, 5L, 62L, 73L, 72L, 47L, 61L, 47L, 
46L, 44L, 43L, 46L, 45L, 16L, 62L, 8L, 48L, 15L, 79L, 62L, 46L, 
62L, 45L, 55L, 21L, 41L, 45L, 46L, 45L, 50L, 62L, 43L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 63L, 17L, 3L, 45L, 2L, 50L, 1L, 44L, 15L, 46L, 46L, 7L, 8L, 
62L, 16L, 47L, 19L, 61L, 46L, 1L, 4L, 48L, 61L, 43L, 46L, 61L, 
44L, 48L, 1L, 5L, 43L, 43L, 46L, 58L, 3L, 55L, 27L, 1L, 47L, 
19L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 48L, 62L, 61L, 23L, 1L, 55L, 19L, 48L, 
1L, 43L, 47L, 1L, 46L, 11L, 46L, 48L, 46L, 32L, 50L, 61L, 62L, 
48L, 46L, 55L, 62L, 55L, 43L, 61L, 47L, 59L, 50L, 10L, 55L, 63L, 
55L, 48L, 31L, 32L, 48L, 55L, 62L, 59L, 53L, 48L, 48L, 62L, 59L, 
4L, 4L, 25L, 59L, 48L, 60L, 43L, 58L, 49L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 63L, 51L, 
55L, 47L, 49L, 55L, 49L, 55L, 13L, 60L, 2L, 13L, 3L, 25L, 7L, 
62L, 62L, 60L, 10L, 61L, 45L, 3L, 11L, 51L, 47L, 1L, 46L, 63L, 
60L, 43L, 62L, 58L, 61L, 1L, 2L, 46L, 1L, 13L, 54L, 48L, 54L, 
45L, 45L, 31L, 48L, 42L, 49L, 43L, 61L, 1L, 31L, 1L, 63L, 11L, 
47L, 39L, 7L, 42L, 1L, 1L, 1L), trop = c(2600L, 1710L, NA, 840L, 
1740L, 5010L, 776L, 7120L, 4281L, 1360L, 15300L, 6490L, NA, 15940L, 
6300L, 6020L, 2100L, 5330L, 1500L, 500L, NA, 1080L, 990L, 1420L, 
NA, 2390L, 3710L, 3340L, 180L, NA, NA, 3600L, 470L, 6390L, 1970L, 
9320L, 2260L, NA, 3930L, 6440L, NA, 4470L, 1800L, 40L, 21876L, 
871L, 7860L, NA, 320L, 8450L, 1730L, 262L, 16720L, 1247L, NA, 
NA, 54592L, 1241L, 2413L, NA, 45649L, NA, NA, 160L, 843L, NA, 
1470L, 372L, 844L, 1454L, 50000L, 11450L, 769L, 2234L, 349L, 
250L, 3654L, 8421L, NA, 5204L, 440L, NA, 40273L, 90L, 9352L, 
2177L, 10014L, 11L, 11135L, 5256L, 1753L, NA, NA, 50L, 8903L, 
3598L, 2483L, NA, NA, NA, 1557L, 5247L, 24L, 2993L, 3624L, 751L, 
NA, NA, 24160L, NA, NA, 5687L, 1911L, NA, NA, 1855L, 9951L, 13374L, 
2107L, 4927L, 83L, 2380L, 663L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1627L, 
NA, 1211L, 5654L, NA, NA, 10000L, NA, NA, NA, 2956L, 67927L, 
NA, 63L, NA, 4790L, NA, NA, 3569L, 961L, 6581L, 253L, 2888L, 
33017L, 1675L, 438L, 15543L, 6212L, 6694L, NA, 1945L, 3004L, 
3789L, NA, 2844L, 950L, 123L, 6630L, 3220L, 2040L, NA, 6672L, 
1480L, 6979L, NA, 1411L, 5711L, NA, 2340L, NA, 57L, NA, 33L, 
5110L, NA, 2797L, 1035L, 2840L, 251L, 7671L, 6155L, 4299L, NA, 
846L, 2339L, 400L, 86115L, 27L, 87355L, NA, 8669L, NA, NA, NA, 
1258L, 3000L, NA, 137L, 3866L, NA, 1312L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2103L, 1586L, 601L, 1472L, 1692L, NA, 2102L, 6452L, NA, NA, 1244L, 
2051L, 1007L, NA, NA, NA, 1726L, 3400L, 2143L, NA, 236L, 3930L, 
31026L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5280L, 1230L), egfr = c(56L, 90L, 75L, 
71L, 71L, 68L, 90L, 78L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 77L, 83L, 52L, 49L, 88L, 
84L, 88L, 81L, 51L, 51L, 87L, 77L, 85L, 76L, 90L, 65L, 48L, 99L, 
90L, 99L, 87L, 62L, 90L, 87L, 59L, 79L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 78L, 90L, 
69L, 90L, 87L, 90L, 58L, 90L, 79L, 55L, 51L, 90L, 58L, 90L, 56L, 
62L, 86L, 61L, 84L, 63L, 63L, 90L, 90L, 85L, 64L, 67L, 45L, 90L, 
78L, 65L, 69L, 90L, 90L, 59L, 54L, 60L, 68L, 86L, 42L, 73L, 90L, 
85L, 63L, 90L, 86L, 68L, 71L, 90L, 68L, 63L, 81L, 76L, 61L, 75L, 
84L, 90L, 90L, 48L, 90L, 77L, 68L, 90L, 64L, 90L, 90L, 61L, 84L, 
80L, 69L, 58L, 65L, 86L, 86L, 46L, 56L, 90L, 46L, 87L, 84L, 68L, 
67L, 72L, 35L, 86L, 74L, 78L, 67L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 76L, 90L, 86L, 
63L, 63L, 53L, 90L, 90L, 75L, 64L, 69L, 68L, 52L, 49L, 90L, 65L, 
86L, 42L, 63L, 90L, 90L, 73L, 75L, 66L, 64L, 90L, 35L, 90L, 82L, 
90L, 84L, 61L, 90L, 86L, 51L, 52L, 69L, 54L, 90L, 75L, 85L, 72L, 
90L, 80L, 54L, 58L, 90L, 89L, 72L, 90L, 84L, 33L, 74L, 36L, 56L, 
61L, 63L, 77L, 84L, 85L, 90L, 90L, 51L, 90L, 90L, 68L, 90L, 52L, 
90L, 48L, 90L, 82L, 86L, 67L, 90L, 76L, 14L, 63L, 59L, 82L, 90L, 
39L, 77L, 90L, 78L, 74L, 54L, 36L, 58L, 69L, NA, 53L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 88L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 63L, 87L, 48L, 90L, 55L, 70L, 
65L, 90L, NA, 90L, 90L, 72L, 66L, 55L), dm = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), smoke = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), delta_mon1_baseline_to_d3 = c(-821.989379882808, 
-562.289733886719, -502.216308593755, -388.549621582031, -372.002563476562, 
-308.033813476562, -283.636077880859, -279.422790527344, -218.279922485352, 
-173.209777832031, -162.939453124998, -95.700927734375, -70.961883544922, 
-69.742797851558, -69.5900268554681, -66.49755859375, -58.77816772461, 
-29.29504394531, -25.714111328125, -12.548919677734, -2.99462890625, 
2.80639648437602, 32.883270263672, 33.036499023438, 44.05969238281, 
47.6982421875, 55.87646484375, 116.716430664065, 130.585632324218, 
131.392028808594, 146.8232421875, 153.190795898438, 159.863708496094, 
164.985534667969, 179.8525390625, 180.041305541992, 192.978088378906, 
208.791275024414, 243.90209960937, 248.09851074219, 327.035522460937, 
336.011077880859, 375.086456298828, 419.108337402341, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), stratum = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), surv = structure(c(30, 
73, 5, 77, 74, 74, 45, 6, 46, 70, 70, 72, 77, 5, 43, 71, 74, 
77, 71, 77, 77, 73, 74, 69, 28, 77, 73, 68, 73, 70, 74, 75, 76, 
69, 69, 78, 69, 58, 78, 71, 76, 76, 69, 71, 43, 44, 5, 62, 73, 
72, 47, 61, 47, 46, 44, 43, 46, 45, 16, 62, 8, 48, 15, 79, 62, 
46, 62, 45, 55, 21, 41, 45, 46, 45, 50, 62, 43, 4, 1, 4, 63, 
17, 3, 45, 2, 50, 1, 44, 15, 46, 46, 7, 8, 62, 16, 47, 19, 61, 
46, 1, 4, 48, 61, 43, 46, 61, 44, 48, 1, 5, 43, 43, 46, 58, 3, 
55, 27, 1, 47, 19, 11, 1, 1, 1, 2, 48, 62, 61, 23, 1, 55, 19, 
48, 1, 43, 47, 1, 46, 11, 46, 48, 46, 32, 50, 61, 62, 48, 46, 
55, 62, 55, 43, 61, 47, 59, 50, 10, 55, 63, 55, 48, 31, 32, 48, 
55, 62, 59, 53, 48, 48, 62, 59, 4, 4, 25, 59, 48, 60, 43, 58, 
49, 1, 8, 1, 63, 51, 55, 47, 49, 55, 49, 55, 13, 60, 2, 13, 3, 
25, 7, 62, 62, 60, 10, 61, 45, 3, 11, 51, 47, 1, 46, 63, 60, 
43, 62, 58, 61, 1, 2, 46, 1, 13, 54, 48, 54, 45, 45, 31, 48, 
42, 49, 43, 61, 1, 31, 1, 63, 11, 47, 39, 7, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(245L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("time", "status")), type = "right", class = "Surv")), row.names = c(NA, 
-245L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: You wrote what data you wanted to use, but not how you wanted to use it. What do you want to do with the information? Do you want to plot the points? Do you want to add the information as text? This plot is a `ggplot` object. You can `+ geom_point` or `+ annotate(geom = "text", x = 20, y = .5, label = "Tell me whatever")` to your plot.  (BTW, in the future, run the function `dput()` with your data object, put that output in your question, and add the libraries you used. You'll get answers a lot quicker!)

Comment: @Kat, I know how to insert text with '''annotate''' but I would like like do it automatically from the cox regression analysis I have performed. Is that possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think you're looking for. First, it isn't built into that plotting function to do this, but you can create these labels dynamically.

It ended up being a bit easier if I changed the name of `stratum` to `Quartile`. If that's what you're labeling it, this shouldn't be too big of an issue.

```
# your code with changed name
# CHANGE here--- changed name from stratum to Quartile
df$Quartile <- findInterval(df$quantile, quantile(df$quantile, na.rm = TRUE)[-5])

# CHANGE here--- changed name from stratum to Quartile
df$Quartile <- factor(df$Quartile)

# CHANGE here--- changed name from stratum to Quartile
cox <- coxph(Surv(mace_months_date_vs_date_sample, mace) ~ Quartile, data = df)
```

Next, I created the labels that I think you're looking for. It made the row names "Quartile1", so I used `gsub` to add a space. I rounded the CI to 2 digits and the p-value to 3. I took the liberty of using `≈` instead of `=`, to denote 'about' instead of 'is.'

```
coxP <- data.frame(summary(cox)$coefficients)[,5]
coxConf <- data.frame(summary(cox)$conf.int) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(p = coxP,
          # this creates the strings for the legend
              # gsub adds space, round, keep trailing zeros
         tag = paste0(rowname %>% gsub("(\\D)(\\d)", "\\1 \\2", .), 
                      " HR ", exp.coef. %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      " (95% CI ",
                      lower..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "-", upper..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "), P ≈ ", p %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.3f", .))) %>% 
  select(tag)
# validate as expected
coxConf
#                                                tag
# 1 Quartile 2 HR 0.62 (95% CI 0.10-3.72), P ≈ 0.601
# 2 Quartile 3 HR 0.30 (95% CI 0.03-2.87), P ≈ 0.295
# 3  Quartile 4 HR 0.00 (95% CI 0.00-Inf), P ≈ 0.999
```

Then your theme content—it is unchanged.

```
# your custom theme; unchanged
custom_theme <- function(){
  theme_survminer() %+replace%
    theme(
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"),
      plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.9)
    )
}
```

This following line of code does the same thing as what you created with mod, essentially. After that, the graph.

```
# model to plot- 
fit <- survfit(Surv(mace_months_date_vs_date_sample, mace) ~ stratum, 
               data = df)
ggsurvplot(fit, 
           data = df,
           test.for.trend = T,
           conf.int = F, 
           censor = F,
           ggtheme = custom_theme(), 
           legend = c(0.5, 0.2),
           legend.title = element_blank(),
           legend.labs = c("Quartile 1", unlist(coxConf)),
           xlab = "Follow-up (months)",
           font.x = c(size = 15),
           ylab = "Survival from MACE",
           font.y = c(size = 15),
           ylim = c(0, 1.05),
           break.y.by = 0.2,
           axes.offset = FALSE,
           palette = c("blue", "dark red", "green", "orange"))
```

The outcome:

[image]

---

---

#### Update

Considering what you wrote for the p-value, I think this should cover it. However, I didn't use ≥ and ≤ because it wouldn't be accurate. However, if you wanted to use them anyway, you can just copy and paste them into the code. You'll just replace them where I've written > and <

Since this only impacts the tag creation, here's that code.

```
# create the tags you wanted
coxP <- data.frame(summary(cox)$coefficients)[,5]
coxConf <- data.frame(summary(cox)$conf.int) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(p = coxP,
         p2 = case_when(       # determine direction
           round(p, 3) > p ~ '>',
           round(p, 3) < p ~ '<',
           round(p, 3) == p ~ '='
         ),
         p3 = ifelse(round(p, 2) == 1, T, F), # id if p value is 1 (too high!)
         # gsub adds space, round, keep trailing zeros
         tag = paste0(rowname %>% gsub("(\\D)(\\d)", "\\1 \\2", .), 
                      " HR ", exp.coef. %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      " (95% CI ",
                      lower..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "-", upper..95 %>% sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", .),
                      "), P ", p2, " ",
                      ifelse(p3,
                             yes = "0.99",    # if p rounded = 1
                             no = sprintf(fmt = "%.2f", p)))) %>% 
  select(tag)
# validate as expected
coxConf
#                                               tag
# 1 Quartile 2 HR 0.62 (95% CI 0.10-3.72), P > 0.60
# 2 Quartile 3 HR 0.30 (95% CI 0.03-2.87), P > 0.29
# 3  Quartile 4 HR 0.00 (95% CI 0.00-Inf), P > 0.99
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly! For the P-values, do you know how I can get a round P-value to 3 when it is <0.01, and to 2 when it is >= 0.01 (for this example, Quartile 2 should be 0.30), and just write P≥0.99 when it is ≥ 0.99 ? It this last case, the quartile 4 should just be like this ```Quartile 4. P≥0.99```, without HR and 95% CI. Same when P-value is less than 0.001, we could write ```P=<0.001```. Again, many thanks Kat.

Comment: I think I've understood what you're asking for—I updated my answer with this information at the end (look for the heading "Update").

Comment: Thank you Kat! it is very appreciated.